# Use svg as a mask with styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, styled-components

I am trying to have an svg show the element behind it while other parts of the behind element are hidden.  I hope that makes sense, to demonstrate here is a sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-firefly-17sy5?file=/src/components/Features.js

I want to be able to see the gradient only within the animated svg and everywhere else to be white.

```
import React from "react";
import styled, { keyframes } from "styled-components";
import { ReactComponent as CardBlob1 } from "../images/blobs/card-blob-1.svg";
import { FaRegClipboard } from "react-icons/fa";

const Features = () => {
  return (
    <Card>
      <BlobContainer>
        <div className="backdropColor"></div>

        <CardBlob1 className="cardBlob" />

        <FaRegClipboard className="card-icon" />
      </BlobContainer>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Features;

const transformBlob = keyframes`
    0%   { transform: scale(1)   rotate(0);  }
    25%  { transform: scale(0.9)  rotate(55deg);   }
    50%  { transform: scale(0.8) rotate(180deg);  }
    75%  { transform: scale(0.9)  rotate(55deg);   }
    100% { transform: scale(1)   rotate(0);  }
`;

const Card = styled.div`
  align-items: center;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px 43px;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  width: 260px;
  }
`;

const BlobContainer = styled.div`
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;

  .cardBlob {
    animation: ${transformBlob} 20s linear infinite;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;

    path {
      fill: inherit;
    }
  }

  .backdropColor {
    height: 100px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
      to top,
      #fcc5e4 0%,
      #fda34b 15%,
      #ff7882 35%,
      #c8699e 52%,
      #7046aa 71%,
      #0c1db8 87%,
      #020f75 100%
    );
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
  }

  .card-icon {
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 25px;
  }
`;
```

and the svg in images:

```
<svg id="visual" transform="translate(128.81 125.55)" width="348.26" height="278.9" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 348.26 278.9" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
<path d="m342.31 70.846c23.3 57.1-25.1 152.2-88.3 189.1-63.1 36.8-140.9 15.5-191.3-25.4-50.4-40.9-73.5-101.4-57.9-147.8 15.6-46.4 69.8-78.8 144.4-85.5 74.7-6.6 169.8 12.5 193.1 69.6" fill="#f4f7ff"/>
</svg>
```

I have Google'd extensively but so far haven't succeeded :/. Please can someone here help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the same issue did you finally find any solution?